# Using xcode to create static library with C, Error: "Undefined symbols for architecture i386"!

Tags: ios, c, xcode, i386

I am using xcode to create a static library with C, I seem to get an error `Undefined symbols for architecture i386`.

The static library project, include three files: `fun.c`, `testFun.cpp`, `testFun.h`

Here is `testFun.cpp`

```
#include "testFun.h"
extern void test_c_fun();
void TestFun::test()
{
    printf("# TestFun c++ # ");
    test_c_fun();
}
```

and here is the `fun.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test_c_fun() 
{ 
    printf("# test_c_fun #"); 
}
```

When I build with "IOS Device" and "iPhone Retina(4-inch)", I get two x.a file.

Using `lipo` tool with `-create` param to output the new x.a, supporting `arm` and `i386`.

add the x.a to my project, and include the testFun head file now code:

```
TestFun tf;
tf.test();
```

Then building it, I get these errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "test_c_fun()", referenced from: TestFun::test() in libstatistic.a(testFun.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

When I hide the c-fun call (test_c_fun), then the build is successful!

look like:

```
#include "testFun.h"
extern void test_c_fun();
void TestFun::test()
{
    printf("# TestFun c++ # ");
    //test_c_fun();
}
```

Why can it not work with C file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In testFun.cpp, declare C functions with extern C

as

```
extern "C" void test_c_fun();
```

C style function have different name mangling rules. When you declare a C function in .cpp file, it will treat that function as a C++ function.

When you will add `extern "C"` before declaration, it will see that function as a C function.